# 'My_Model' object is not iterable using customtag in django

Tags: django

I am new to Django and I am trying to make my data accessible to templates in different apps by creating custom tags in Django.

my model.py

```
from django.db import models

class my_Model(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   age = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

my custom tag file `templatetag/custom_tag.py`(why I did this is to make my data accessible to templates in different apps)

```
from django import template
from model_file.models import my_Model

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_custom_tag_fn():
    return my_Model.objects.order_by('-pk')[0]
```

my html file

```
{% load custom_tag %}
{% get_custom_tag_fn as ct %}
    {% for item in ct %}
    <p> {{ item }} </p>
     {% endfor %}
```

I am getting the error `'My_Model' object is not iterable`. Any thought about how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
return my_Model.objects.order_by('-pk')[0]
```

Model objects.order_by(...) returns queryset, alike to the list it`s a collection, so with [0] index you take the first object of that collection which of course is not iterable (it's just a single object). So, after that, when you trying to iterate:

```
  {% for item in ct %}
       ...
```

you`re catching this error.

Comment: instead of  `my_Model.objects.order_by('-pk')[0]` I tried `my_Model.objects.all`. it displays all my model objects. I want only the newly created one. As well as I could not get the data in the model instance all I get is `my_Model object(1)`

Comment: Well if you just want one, why are you iterating in the template? Remove the for loop.

Comment: @BczImHappy, using pk for that it`s not good idea, better to have created field in the model, also is better to use first or last (objects.(...).last(), objects.(...).first() (in case if your queryset is empty it just would return None instead of raising IndexError. And, as Daniel wrote just remove iteration from the template, for a single object is not needed

Comment: @DanielRoseman  Then how do I get the name and age from my `my_Model object`

Comment: @BczImHappy, ct.name, ct.age I suppose